# Visa requirements for Filipino traveling to Costa Rica via South Korea and USA

Tags: air-travel, usa, transit, filipino-citizens, costa-rica

I'm from Philippines and planning to visit Costa Rica.  Do I need a transit visa to go through Dallas Texas.

Airlines: Philippines and American. Departing: Manila Philippines. Arriving: San Jose Costa Rica,

Route: Manila - Seoul, Seoul - Dallas Texas, Dallas Texas. - Costa Rica.

I just have my Passport, a plane ticket and a letter of invitation.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Costa_Rica), Phillipine citizens have visa-free entry to Costa Rica for visits of up to 30 days.

**However**, you will need an U.S. visa for the transfer in Dallas. American airports don't offer any kind of visa-free transit.

Visa-free transit should be available in Seoul if you don't leave the airport.

Comment: But sir,  I don't leave in Dallas airport, just going to wait my time for the COSTA rica my arriving...  do I still need visa/transit visa?

Comment: @josel: Yes. _Everyone_ who is on a plane that arrives at an American airport from another country has to go through US immigration, even if they leave immediately afterwards. American airports don't have any "international zone" for transiting passengers.